# Windows Phone: Load HTML source with HTTPWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to download the entire desktop-site HTML code with my WP7 app. I used the following code in normal Win32 apps which isn't working in WP. Especially, I can't find at `GetReponse` property of `HtttpWebReqest`. And I can't use `WebBrowser` as it's not loading the desktop site, only mobile site. Any help?

```
        request = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
        response = request.GetResponse
        sr = New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

        Source = sr.ReadToEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

In wp7 only async request are allowed. Maybe WebClient would be the easiest for you.

Here is an example:

```
private void loadFeedButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);

    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri("http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/rss.aspx"));
}

// Event handler which runs after the feed is fully downloaded.
private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Showing the exact error message is useful for debugging. In a finalized application, 
            // output a friendly and applicable string to the user instead. 
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        });
    }
    else
    {
       this.State["feed"] = e.Result;          
    }
}
```